# Filling in a word document programatically with python?

Tags: python, ms-word, ms-office

I have a word document that we send out to customers.  There are only a few things that change - name of the customer, company, and a table with costs that could be a varying number of rows (between 1 - 4).

Right now, we use a pdf reporting library that works o\fine, but in some places if the text is too long, then it runs underneath the table and can't shift the table itself.  Also no one here can edit it.

I want to know if there is a way to, using python (or another program that I can call with python/a batch file), programatically create a word document, give it some parameters, and save it as a .doc.  I imagine perhaps feeding it a dictionary like `{"customerName": "customer", "clientName": "John Smith", "address": "123 Fake Street", "billCost": 100.00, ...}`

Is this possible?

Comment: I did a similar thing with python-docx. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @Chris Thanks. How would you do it?

Comment: @bjk116 There are plenty of examples online.  Try looking at the dockx link posted in the previous comment.  Build something using that and if you get stuck create a new question.

Comment: I did check that out, I had tried looking on google, stack overflow is my last resort.  python-docx might not be an option for our environment.  Did you have any other ways in mind?

Comment: Why doesn't python-docx work for your environment? Please provide the constraints you have.